# Is the acyclic chromatic number bounded in terms of the book thickness?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

ISGCI says that the chromatic number of a graph is upper bounded in terms of the book thickness.
https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/par_32.html

This can be improved by saying that the book thickness bounds the degeneracy.

A further improvement would be that the book thickness bounds the acyclic chromatic number.

Is it true? Is there a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that "book thickness bounds the acyclic chromatic number" was
established in this paper:

> Dujmovic, Vida, Attila Pór, and David R. Wood. "Track layouts of graphs." *Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science* 6, no. 2 (2004).
>   [arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0407033).

In the Abstract they say,

> "As corollaries we
>   prove that acyclic chromatic number is bounded by both queue-number and stack-number."

And then later (Section 5), they say,

> "Note that stack-number is also called *page-number* and *book-thickness*."

Not sure if this is relevant to your quesiton, but
the acyclic chromatic number is not bounded by *geometric thickness*
$\overline{\theta}(G)$.

Comment: The literature can be confusing with four names for the same quantity: book-thickness, page-number, stack-number, and fixed outer-thickness. I would be interested to learn how this proliferation occurred, as book-thickness is ~50 yrs old.

Comment: Hi Joe. Page-number is descriptive, but does not connect with related topics. Stack-number is  used because in some sense it is dual to queue-number. Book-thickness is used  to highlight the similarity with thickness (minimum k such that G is the union of k planar graphs). Fixed outer-thickness also make sense, since book-thickness is the minimum k such that G has an edge partition into k outerplanar graphs with a fixed ordering of the vertices.

Comment: ... my personal favourite is "convex thickness", since it is really a straight-line drawing with the vertices in convex position.

Comment: An indirect answer to the original quesiton is that graphs of bounded book thickness have bounded expansion (in the sense of Nesetril and Ossona de Mendez). So they have bounded generalised colouring numbers. So they have bounded acylic chromatic number.